# VB2008 Resolution-based resizing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, resolution

Usually I am a web developer so this is probably a very novice question. I recently made an app in VB2008, but I developed it in a huge reso (1920x1200). The person that will be using it still uses 800x600 reso. Is there any simple way I can resize the entire interface to fit any resolution? I didn't really think about it at all while I was making the program.

Comment: Is it a web app or a desktop app?

Comment: @Daniel, I was wondering the same because he started with "Usually I am a web developer" but it is tagged 'web-developement' after all...

Comment: I did not tag this web-development, it must have done it automatically. It is a desktop app in VB 2008.

Comment: so what is it? Winforms or WPF?

Comment: I suppose it is whatever is default. I really don't know, I downloaded VB 2008 Express Edition and made a new project, then made it from there. Sorry again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's any simple way of changing your application. If you were writing an application from scratch I'd suggest looking at the `Dock`, `Anchor`, `MinSize` and `MaxSize` properties of the controls, all of which are quite useful to make them resize according to the total size of the application. Could be a bit annoying if you have to go in and change them all manually now though.

There's also the `TableLayoutPanel` control, you can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx).